# Sorting the main diagonal of matrix from smallest number to largest

Tags: python, sorting, matrix

Sorting the main diagonal of matrix from smallest number to largest

```
def sort_main_diag():
    f = int(input("number of rows: "))
    c = int(input("number of columns: "))
    m = []
    read_matrix(m,f,c)
   
    for i in range(f):
        for j in range(c):
            if i == j:
                for k in range(i+1,f):
                    if m[i][j] > m[k][j]:
                        aux = m[i][j]
                        m[i][j] = m[k][j]
                        m[k][j] = aux
    for row in m:
        print(row)
```

However this code does nothing to the matrix where is my mistake?

the main diagonal is this

[image]

note read_matrix is

```
def read_matrix(m,f,c):
    for i in range(f):
        a  = []
        for j in range(c):
            a.append(int(input("Ingrese el dato: ")))
        m.append(a)
```

Comment: noteice how if i = j we are in the main diag

Comment: @shaikmoeed the function that ask for the input of the elements of a matrix

Comment: @KellyBundy the sorting procces of the main diag is my problem

Comment: @KellyBundy I consider adequate to include read_matrix to see how matrix is defined in this example

Comment: @shaikmoeed yes I am calling the function

Comment: @shaikmoeed yes the mian diag is not sorted and some elements of the matrix change

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

instead of using nested loops, there is an another solution, which is called Python List Comprehension. You can find more about Python Comprehension [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp). So, what I am going to do is basically extract the main diagonal element from the matrix and I am going to print the sorted list using Python list sort() function. Hope this helps you.

```
def sort_main_diag():

rows = int(input("rows: "))
columns = int(input("columns: "))
matrix = []

leer_matrix(matrix, rows, columns)

# Store the main diagonal elements in a list
diagonal_elements = [matrix[i][i] for i in range(min(rows, columns))]
diagonal_elements.sort()

# Print the list of diagonal elements
print("Main Diagonal Elements:")
for element in diagonal_elements:
    print(element)
```